# SQL: FOREIGN KEY prevents destruction of links between tables

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

Refer: [w3schools-SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

It states:

**The FOREIGN KEY constraint is used to prevent actions that would destroy links between tables.** Can someone give an example of an action that foreign key would prevent ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say we have the two tables **Employees** and **Departments**. Each department has a unique number, and for each employee we list the number of the department that he or she works on. We have also declared this as a foreign key.

In that case the foreign key would prevent a number of actions:

- Inserting a new employee who works on a department that doesn't exist
- Deleting a department where there are employees who work
- Updating an employee by changing the department he or she works on to a department that doesn't exist
- Updating a department by changing its number, if there are employees who work on that department
- Destroying the department table

All this is to ensure that when the database says that an employee works on a certain department, then that department will actually exist in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Table Employee has its primary key set to empid.

Table Address references (foreign key constraint) empid in Table Employee

If you try deleting employee '1011' from Table Employee and that employee has a record in Table Address the delete will not go through because of the dependency. Unless you have cascading delete set up..

Answer (score 0):

Table Users

```
ID   UserName
1    msmucker0527
2    Jake
```

Table Email (Foreign Key: UserID = Users.ID)

```
UserID    Email
1         msmucker0527@email.net
2         jake@email.net
```

You cannot add a record to the Email table with a UserID that does not exist in the Users Table.  This way you don't have email addresses that are not "linked" to a User.  You would also be prevented from deleting a user without first removing the email address so that it would not become stranded